# cannot find Chrome binary when executing python test in jenkins

Tags: python, selenium, jenkins

i'm using python and selenium to execute a test form my application.
The code is written in eclipse NEON and it works fine when i execute from eclipse.
But when i use jenkins to run the same code it says: Cannot find chrome binary.
What i did in jenkins is to execute as Windows bact command.
i write a batch code like:

```
C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe C:\Users\Me\NEON\workspace\Test1\test-package\test.py
```

i saved this code into a file named run_test1.bat
Then i put this line in jenkins as:

```
call "C:\Users\Me\NEON\workspace\Test1\test-package\run_test1.bat"
```

This the error stack from jenkins:

```
20:22:57 C:\Users\Me\NEON\workspace\Test1\test-package>C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\python.exe C:\Users\Me\NEON\workspace\Test1\test-package\test.py 
20:23:03 E
20:23:03 ======================================================================
20:23:03 ERROR: test_x (__main__.Login)
20:23:03 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
20:23:03 Traceback (most recent call last):
20:23:03   File "C:\Users\Me\NEON\workspace\Test1\test-package\test.py", line 33, in setUp
20:23:03     self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Selenium-driver\\chromedriver.exe")
20:23:03   File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
20:23:03     desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
20:23:03   File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
20:23:03     self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
20:23:03   File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 179, in start_session
20:23:03     response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
20:23:03   File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 238, in execute
20:23:03     self.error_handler.check_response(response)
20:23:03   File "C:\Users\Me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 193, in check_response
20:23:03     raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
20:23:03 selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: cannot find Chrome binary
20:23:03   (Driver info: chromedriver=2.29.461591 (62ebf098771772160f391d75e589dc567915b233),platform=Windows NT 6.1.7601 SP1 x86_64)
20:23:03 
20:23:03 
20:23:03 ----------------------------------------------------------------------
20:23:03 Ran 1 test in 5.095s
20:23:03 
20:23:03 FAILED (errors=1)
20:23:03 
20:23:03 C:\Users\Me\NEON\workspace\Test1\test-package>exit 1 
20:23:03 Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure
20:23:03 Finished: FAILURE
```

My python code starts like this:

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoAlertPresentException
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities    
import unittest, time, re
from util import Util
import logging 
from selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection import LOGGER
LOGGER.setLevel(logging.ERROR)


class Login(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        '''options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.binary_location = ("C://Users//Me//AppData//Local//Google//Chrome//Application//")
        chrome_driver_binary = ("C://Selenium-driver//chromedriver.exe")
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_driver_binary, chrome_options=options)'''


        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome("C:\\Selenium-driver\\chromedriver.exe")
```

Can someone help me ti figure out this problem in jenkins.
i;m using Jenkins ver. 2.89

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a problem in your jenkins slave configuration.

Jenkins needs to be logged as a standard windows user account in order to run your script. You need to be sure that user is able to run your script (do not use path to the chrome binary under your personal user account directory. Install chrome for all users).

The selenium script need a desktop to launch the browser, so do not forget to configure your VM with auto login to this user account (a desktop will be available for your jenkins slave).

For the configuration of your jenkins slave, see documentation here:  [Step by step guide to set up master and slave machines on Windows](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Step+by+step+guide+to+set+up+master+and+slave+machines+on+Windows)